# String parameters in Processing class

Tags: constructor, processing

I am making a pong game in Processing and I have my pattles on their own class.

I have 3 parameters in the constructor which are tf, keyUp, and KeyDown.

I have tf as a boolean, but I need keyUp and keyDown to be a string.

How do I set them as a string??

```java
class Pattle {

  float keyUpLeft;
  float keyDownLeft;
  float keyUpRight;
  float keyDownRight;
  boolean LeftRight;

  Pattle(boolean tf, float keyUp, float keyDown) {
    if (tf == false) {
      keyUpLeft = keyUp;
      keyDownLeft = keyDown;
    } else {
      keyUpRight = keyUp;
      keyDownRight = keyDown;
    }
    LeftRight = tf;
  }

  void keyPressed() {
    if (key == keyUpLeft) {
      print("UP");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. To make them a `String` value, you'd just change their types to `String`:

```
String keyUpLeft;
String keyDownLeft;
String keyUpRight;
String keyDownRight;
boolean LeftRight;

Pattle(boolean tf, String keyUp, String keyDown) {
```

But if you're comparing them to `key`, then you want them to be `char` types, not `String` types, since `key` is a `char`.